# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in browser using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Good morning everyone, i'm quite new to Docker and i'm trying to learn it with a simple project. Currently i have a client container and a service container, with their respective Dockerfiles as follow:

```
#Server Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

```
#Client Dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR './src/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

RUN apk update 
RUN apk add curl

COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

```
#docker-compose

version: "0.0.0"

services:
  client:
    build: Ecommerce-client/
    container_name: ecommerce-client
    ports: #per essere chiamato dall'esterno
      - 4200:4200 
    networks:
      - ecommerce
  
  server:
    build: Ecommerce-products/
    container_name: ecommerce-product
    networks:
      - ecommerce
    expose: #la porta che espone all'interno della nostra network
      - "8080"

networks:
  ecommerce:
    driver: bridge
```

The simple client just show a list of objects sent by the service, in localhost everything works just fine but then when i try with the docker-compose file, i get the error **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**.

In my ts client i have one simple call to the service as follow:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>("http://ecommerce-product:8080/products").subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
    });
```

I tryed to create a bash inside my client and make a call with curl and everything works, but when i open it in my browser it doesn't work. What could be my problem? Thank you!

Comment: And `http://ecommerce-product` resolves to? Please also show the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Check whether or not you forwarded the port to the host machine. The *docker-compose* file will show you that information.

Comment: sorry i forgot, i added it with an edit

Comment: Is "http://ecommerce-product:8080/products" a valid URL? Am I missing something here?

Comment: i saw it in another thread, they sayed you can use the container_name to link the two containers so they know how to communicate. I make the same call in curl and i get the response

Comment: The browser isn't in a container and can't see the Docker-network host names.  This also extends to your front-end application; even if its code is served from a container, the actual application runs in the browser, and outside of Docker.  In a developer setup, the easiest thing to do is to add `ports:` for the backend and connect to `localhost` and the backend's published port.

Comment: thanks a lot @DavidMaze, this helped me a lot to understand. This almost solved my issue, now i get CORS policy error but i have enabled CORS in my backend. Do you have any tip for me? also i would like to accept your answer if you want to submit it

Comment: @SamuelePipitone If you get a CORS issue, something is obviously wrong with your CORS setup. Post the exact error (also look in the console of the browser, you will see exactly what's missing) and what you did to "enable CORS" in the backend ...

Comment: @doneforaiur If the system has the means to resolve `ecommerce-product`, why not? You can for instance define an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file, or as it is the case here, the docker runtime is able to resolve container names from the `docker-compose.yml` to the respective containers ...

Comment: @derpirscher since OP gets a "name not resolved" error, my first instinct that there were some kind of typo. Didn't know docker runtime could resolve names from the docker-compose file, will check that out, thanks! :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David Maze commented: The browser isn't in a container and can't see the Docker-network host names. This also extends to your front-end application; even if its code is served from a container, the actual application runs in the browser, and outside of Docker. In a developer setup, the easiest thing to do is to add ports: for the backend and connect to localhost and the backend's published port